# Reading process name from /proc/ID/cmdline using null chars don't work

Tags: c++, algorithm, process

I'm trying to create a small program that can read all pid and yours names from the /proc, i already saw that to do it i need substr by null chars. It works very well but in some cases it just don't work. look the following results:

```
Proc ID: 3440
Proc name: code

Proc ID: 2588
Proc name: zsh

Proc ID: 2450
Proc name: app --enable-sandbox --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=9 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --vscode-window-config=vscode:30d26ee9-f58e-4c70-8410-066d00859f6c
```

In the last result of my search the null byte looks not exists. Here is my methods to read the procs:

```
class process{
public:
    vector<pair<int,string>> getProcess(){
        vector<pair<int,string>> allProcess;

        // Some necessary variables;
        fs::path filePath;
        fstream fileToRead;
        string fileLine;
        string finalExecutableName;
        string processID;

        // For each file in /proc do...
        for(auto file : fs::directory_iterator(procDir)){
            // Get the folder name to check if is numeric
            processID = this->getExecutableOrFolderName(file.path().c_str());
            if(this->directoryNameIsNumeric(processID)){
                // Get the path and append /cmdline
                filePath = file.path();
                filePath.concat("/cmdline");

                // Open the file
                fileToRead.open(filePath.c_str(),ios::in);

                if(fileToRead.is_open()){
                    // Get the line and check if is not null
                    getline(fileToRead,fileLine);
                    if(fileLine != ""){
                        // Try get the executable name
                        finalExecutableName = this->getExecutableOrFolderName(fileLine);
                        
                        // Push the result and the pid to vector
                        allProcess.push_back(make_pair(atoi(processID.c_str()),finalExecutableName));
                    }
                    fileLine = "";
                }
                else{

                }
                fileToRead.close();
            }
        }
        return allProcess;
    };
private:

    bool directoryNameIsNumeric(string folderName){
        size_t folderNameSize = folderName.length();
        for(int i = 0; i < folderNameSize;i++){
            if(!isdigit(folderName[i])){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    //Some possible error here ?
    string getExecutableOrFolderName(string fileText){
        size_t nullPosition = fileText.find('\0');
        if(nullPosition != string::npos){
            fileText = fileText.substr(0,nullPosition);
        }
        return fileText.substr(fileText.rfind("/") + 1);
    }
};
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: why did you need to search the null byte  ?

Comment: Usually the null byte is the connection between the executable path (that has the executable name) and the program arguments. The first "code" program has "/path/to/code--programArgs=value" in the cmdline file, and then when i split by null byte and get the first part i can have the result. you know another way to do that ?

Comment: i think when you print out the command of app ` app --enable-sandbox --num-raster-threads=4 ...` .words was separated by '  ' space -> let's try split command line by space instead of '\0'.